# SublimeText 3 - dynamically enable/disable invisible white space option

Tags: sublimetext3

Is there a dynamic way to enable and disable invisible white space display apart from persistent setting, via:

```
"draw_white_space": "all",
```

Comment: What do you mean by "dynamic way"? LIke a menu entry or key binding or something along those lines?

Comment: Shortcut key - to enable/disable invisible view option.

Answer (score 6):

The only way to control the state of the display for white space is via changing the setting that you reference in your question, `draw_white_space`:

```json
// Set to "none" to turn off drawing white space, "selection" to draw only the
// white space within the selection, and "all" to draw all white space
"draw_white_space": "selection",
```

For many such settings that are a Boolean value, you can bind a key to the `toggle_setting` command, telling it what setting that you want to toggle between. However, for the case of the `draw_white_space` option, it takes a string argument of either `"all"`, `"selection"` or `"none"` and so the standard toggle command won't work.

The following is a simple plugin that implements a `toggle_white_space` command which performs this operation for you. To use it, select `Tools > Developer > New Plugin...` from the menu, replace the stub code you see with the plugin code here, and then save it as a `.py` file in the location that Sublime will default to (your `User` package):

```python
import sublime
import sublime_plugin


class ToggleWhiteSpaceCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit, options=["none", "selection", "all"]):
        try:
            current = self.view.settings().get("draw_white_space", "selection")
            index = options.index(current)
        except:
            index = 0

        index = (index + 1) % len(options)
        self.view.settings().set("draw_white_space", options[index])
```

The defined command takes an optional argument named `options` which allows you to specify the values that you want to toggle between, with the default being all of the possible options.

You can bind a key directly to the command to toggle the state of the setting between all of the possible values of the setting, or use something like the following if you only want to swap between it always being on and always being off, for example:

```json
{
    "keys": ["super+s"],
    "command": "toggle_white_space",
    "args": {
        "options": ["all", "none"]
    }
},
```

Note that although this is changing the setting, it's applying the setting directly to the currently focused view, which is persistent but only to the view in question and only as long as that view is open. This doesn't alter the setting for other files that are already open or for any new files that you might open in the future; the default for such files will still be what you have the setting set to in your user preferences.